# Updating xlink:href doesn't read CSS of source element in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, svg, safari

I'm trying to code SVG with some scripting. One of the issue I encountered is changing `xlink:href` for `<use />` element in Safari - it turns black after setting this attribute. It works fine in Chrome.

Test page is at http://test.ukleja.info/xlink-test.svg

Clicking on the grey circle (which is `<use />` element) should change `xlink:href` attribute and links to another `<symbol>` element defined in `<defs>` and make it blue.

Below I'm pasting the code:

```
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <script>
        function newUse () {
            document.getElementById('myUse').setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#newUse')
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .existing {
            stroke: #666;
            stroke-width: 16;
            fill: #ccc;
        }
        .new {
            stroke: #3399ff;
            stroke-width: 16;
            fill: #99ccff;
        }
    </style>
    <defs>
        <symbol id="existingUse" style="overflow:visible">
            <circle cx="48" cy="48" r="48" class="existing" />
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="newUse" style="overflow:visible">
            <circle cx="48" cy="48" r="48" class="new" />
        </symbol>
    </defs>
    <use id="myUse" xlink:href="#existingUse" x="64" y="64" onclick="newUse()" />
</svg>
```

Please help me and tell me what is wrong. Thanks.

---

After many trials I found the reason - it does not depend on namespaces, xlink or anything like that - as far as I know. Hence I changed the topic a little bit.

Safari does not read class/style of the `symbol` element that `use` element refers to. Changing style inline directly in the `symbol` element solves the problem. However it is still not desired behaviour of Safari.

Any ideas?

Comment: One more strange behaviour in Safari:
Initially circle is grey with dark-grey outline. When you click it, it changes to black without any stroke, which is not desired effect. But when you zoom, it instantly changes to blue circle with dark-blue outline - as it should be. I don't get it.

Comment: did you ever find an answer or workaround for this? I've run into the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion (long shot).  Try just using 'href' in your call, rather than 'xlink:href'.  Ie.:

```
setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', '#newUse')
```

I can't test it myself because I'm on Safari 5.1.7 for Windows and it doesn't seem to support SVG scripts at all.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Safari behaves weird - in both cases. It adds `href` attribute leaving `xlink:href` unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Try use SVGUseElement's api.

```
document.getElementById('myUse').href.baseVal = '#newUse';
```

Try SVGSVGElement's forceRedraw method.

```
document.documentElement.forceRedraw();
```

Comment: The same effect :/ but I found where is the problem - it's CSS - it has no relation (as I understand) with `setAttributeNS`. I'll extend the description in my first post.
Thanks.

Comment: I think that redrawing would be the workaround. However I don't know how to implement it :/. Thank you once again.